# Calling stylesheets in Rails 3.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

Im not sure if this is the best way to do things in rails 3.1 but I am trying to organise my CSS so that its not in one big file I.e. application.css, so instead I am creating page specific views and calling like so

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "gallery", "home" %>
```

Now what I have noticed is that no matter what page you are on it will call all the css within the stylesheet? Is there a way to call just the CSS relevant to that page, or say call just the application and gallery page for example? or am I going about this the wrong way, is there a more efficient way?

All advice appreciated

Comment: Is upgrading to 3.2 an option?

Comment: Yes i can do this. What difference will this make?

Comment: I was going to say you get the asset pipeline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which does this automatically for you (ie. creates a stylesheet per model) - but I just checked and it should already be in 3.1. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application.css you get

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Remove the line for `*= require_tree .` and you will no longer have it dragging in everything else automatically.

Comment: ok thanks, so the require_tree . is only useful if i want everything to be called all the time?

Comment: it's generally a good thing because user's download the entire stylesheet once and the browser never has to update it unless the content changes. this usually speeds things up overall if most of the sheets get used in the site.

Comment: so is it better to put all style sheets in application.css then as a rule of thumb?

Comment: no. if you use scaffolds then you will find it creates additional stylesheets for those things. so you might have a people.css for the people pages. In my experience, segment it as meaningfully as you like. If there really is anything super unusual on your site that only gets used once a blue moon, consider using `*= require_directory .` and putting the stylesheet in a subdirectory and referencing it manually from the view. I had the same concerns as you though, but it seems to be best practise to let rails include all in one file